# Template is missing using Rails 4.2.4/React 0.14.6 and Devise 4.0/babel-core 6.7.4/webpack 1.12.14

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, reactjs, devise, webpack

I've added the Devise 4.0 (it is a flexible authentication solution) in my test app and it was working so good. However, when i was coding the option to update the profile in the index view. I'm getting the following error:

Missing template profile/update, application/update with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "/Users/jalanya/Documents/dev/ruby/twitter-clone/app/views" * "/Users/jalanya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/devise-4.0.0/app/views"

For now, i only have a view below the folder views/profile called "index.html.erb". so, my question is should i add another view template for the action "profile#update"? if so, how can I do that?

I have my test app in github if you would like to test as well. Please find below the files that i have so far.

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get 'profile' => 'profile#index'
  post 'profile' => 'profile#update'

  devise_for :users
  root 'home#index'
end
```

**profile_controller.rb**

```
class ProfileController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  def index
  end
  def update
  end
end
```

**views/profile/index.html.erb**

```
<h2>Update profile</h2>
<%= form_tag "/profile" do %>
  <div class="row">
    <form class="col s12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input name="first_name" id="first_name" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input name="last_name" id="last_name" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
        </div>
        </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button type="submit" class="btn right">Save</button>
      </div>
    </form>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

Please let me know your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to add an update view or comment out that line in your routes file. Right now, you are telling routes about a view that does not exist.

To add it you can type "rails generate view" or manually do it.